# MicrosoftAccount credentials does not work on RDP between two PCs in a particular direction

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, microsoft-account

So I setup my home computer and my work computer under the same LAN via VPN, both of which have my Microsoft Account as login. I was able to do a remote desktop from work to home with Microsoft Account (my MSN email address) but when doing the other direction from home to work, the tool gave me a message

```
The credentials that were used to connect to 192.168. did not work. 
The logon attempt failed.
```

Both accounts are in Administrators group and had RDP permissions.

Both computers were upgraded form Win 7 to Win 10 so both of them had a different user name that worked before the transit to Win 10 and MS account.

Any thoughts on the reason of this weird situation?

Comment: 192.168.?.? -- are you missing the last two octets?

Comment: No sir I just masked it :) had I omitted it the message would be "can't find the computer"

Comment: Haha -- well I am all about security but since you are probably behind a firewall router I don't think anyone would bother you. Next question: are both "Pro" versions? In order to RDP both ways, both need to be Pro.